# How to organize files from dependencies in a Maven shaded jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

When you build a fat jar using the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), there might be conflicts between files at the same path but originating from different dependencies. Similarly, it becomes hard to distinguish the origin of various dependency-specific files located at the root of the individual dependencies (LICENSE.txt, native libraries, ...) when they are placed side-by-side at common locations in the shaded jar.

maven-shade-plugin itself and the similar [jarjar-maven-plugin](https://sonatype.github.io/jarjar-maven-plugin/) appear to provide functionality for automatically relocating *classes*, but not other files from the dependencies, such as those seen in the following example:

## Example of current messy structure

```
/
  - NOTICE
  - magic.gz
  - LICENSE.txt
  - LICENSE
  - asm-license.txt
  / META-INF
    - LICENSE.TXT
    - about.html
  / com.some.library
    <class files>
  / com.some.other.library
    <class files>
  / com.some.third.library
    <class files>
```

This is an example from a project I just started. None of the files above were added by me, but all come from various popular third party libraries I'm using. I would like to clean up this mess by having Maven reorganize files in a common package structure like in the following example:

## Example of desired clean structure

```
/
  / com.some.library
    <class files>
    - NOTICE
    - LICENSE
    / META-INF
      - about.html
  / com.some.other.library
    <class files>
    - magic.gz
    - LICENSE.txt
  / com.some.third.library
    <class files>
    - asm-license.txt
    / META-INF
      - LICENSE.TXT
```

I have many dependencies, so I don't consider writing dependency-specific filters/relocators/... with hard-coded filenames a good solution to this problem.

How do you organize *all* files from dependencies in your shaded jar automatically? Ideally by relocating all files from a dependency inside a subfolder named after the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a Maven best practice...but that being said one possible way to do this would be to create your own Maven plugin based on the maven-shade-plugin. The code base is quite straightforward. You could implement `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceTransformer` and call it in the `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader` class when it enumerates each Jar & Jar entry (you could organize the resource by jar name, perhaps). If you want a basic implementation, I'll post one.

Comment: What is the Maven best practice then? Please feel free to provide an implementation if you feel like it could solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - busy weekend. This would break jars that expect resources in the root directory. That being said, I forked the maven-shade-plugin and edited it to support root resource relocation. It's a very basic implementation, but I did unit test a simple case. Clone the repo here https://github.com/aoetalks/shadeplus-maven-plugin, and run mvn clean install on the shadeplus-maven-plugin project. There is an example project in shadeplus-maven-test-project, in which you can compare my plugin vs the original shade plugin. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check it out! Will report back afterwards.

Comment: I looked at your code. It appears like it only relocates files located in the root of the shaded .jar. What i was asking was "How do you organize *all* files from dependencies in your shaded jar automatically? Ideally by relocating all files from a dependency inside a subfolder named after the dependency."

Comment: My bad. I misread your request because of the description of root files behavior (I did find the relocation of only root resources rather odd :)) I'll make the chance when I get the chance and push it.

Comment: No problem. I added an example to my original post clarifying my issue.